# Reason column missing from contact import error list

Tags: contacts, import

After importing a CSV file of contacts, the rows with errors can be downloaded and fixed. Today I noticed that the "Reason" column is missing from this error list. For example the Import_errors.csv file might contain this:

```
    "Line Number","Reason","First Name","Last Name","Email - Home"
    "1","Joe","Blow","joe@example.com"
```

So in this example there are 5 column headers but only 4 data elements. That is consistently how these files appear, one column is missing. This is Civicrm 5.35.1 on Wordpress 5.7.1. Any ideas?

Comment: I do see reason on error csv when importing on 5.35.1. Do you know any specific reason why the row failed to import after going through the record?

Comment: The above is just an example. Earlier today I imported 4 CSV files and got an error listing from all 4, with a total of 28 error records which is approximately 20% of the import. All 4 were missing the reason column as described. Without a stated reason it is hard to tell what went wrong but I will look for a pattern and post an update. Based on your experience with 5.35.1 though, it sounds like it is an issue with my data or my installation. I don't know how to debug that.

Comment: Here is the update: All of the errors I checked were due to duplicate records in the database. The dupes appear to be all coming from the Woocommerce-Civicrm plugin, so that is a separate issue. But this does not explain why the import errors file is missing the reason code for duplicate records.

Comment: Similar issue maybe here: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2566